# NullPointerException being masked as an HTTP 405 error

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets

**Problem:**
I have some code on the server side that generates a null pointer exception. Normally this causes an HTTP 500 error code and my default error page for that code gets called. For whatever reason the error is getting displayed to browsers as a 405 error, (Method Not Allowed).

```
UserNode userNode= UserGraph.getNode(adjacencyList.get(i)); // This list is empty
```

The cause for the null pointer I have solved but why is Apache Tomcat masking this as a 405 and not a 500 exception?

**Question:** Are there any common reasons why a null pointer exception would cause a HTTP 405 error?

Comment: None that I can think of.  That just sounds *wrong*.

Comment: I'm with you on that. The 405 error is only generated for one user on a page that works for every other user. Basically, the user is no longer present in the graph.

Comment: Is your default error page implemented using a servlet? This behavior could happen if your have an error handling servlet that only implements doGet() and the exception occurs in the doPost() method of another servlet.

Comment: Nice idea man. I'm looking into that right now!!!

Comment: @DavidLevesque that was the problem indeed. If you don't want to post that as an answer I will incase anyone else runs into this issue.

Comment: Added it as an anser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior could happen if you have an error handling servlet that only implements doGet() and the exception occurs in the doPost() method of another servlet (or vice-versa).

Comment: Fantastic. Probably already obvious from the answer, but for completeness sake. The same problem exists for the other http requests types (`doDelete`,  `doPut`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an error mapping in any of the web.xml files in your environment? If there is, it possible that tomcat tries to fetch an error page for code 500 and while doing so something causes it to return 405 instead.

Answer (score -1):

Based on David Levesque answer: the best scenario for error handling servlet is to override service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) method of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
     // your code to handle all types of requests: GET, POST, PUT, etc. 
}
```